# Ajax : only call the ajax if element existing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

for example i have a `.ajax()` function like below:

```
function trend() {
    return $.ajax({
        url: '/dashboard/getTrend' + '?period=30d' + "&profileId=" + $(".numberOfProfile0").html(), //getting the api
        type: 'get',
        success: function(data) {

        }
    });
}
```

It works fine,but i'd like to add a if statement to detect whether the `$(".numberOfProfile0").html()` exist or not, and will only execute when the `$(".numberOfProfile0").html()`exist

I tried below but it doesn't seem right

```
if ($(".numberOfProfile0").length) {
    function trend() {
        return $.ajax({
            url: '/dashboard/getTrend' + '?period=30d' + "&profileId=" + $(".numberOfProfile0").html(), //getting the api
            type: 'get',
            success: function(data) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

**- UPDATE:**

Let's show the whole application
This is the function:

```
  if($(".numberOfProfile0").html().length){
                    function trend1() {
                          return $.ajax({
                            url: '/dashboard/getTrend' + '?period=30d' + "&profileId=" + $(".numberOfProfile0").html(), //getting the api
                            type: 'get',
                            success: function(data) {

                            }
                          });
                        }
                    }

$.when(trend1()).done(function(trend1_data) {

                        //do something
}
```

Comment: `$(".numberOfProfile0").html().length` try this instead of `if ($(".numberOfProfile0").length) {`

Comment: Just `console.log` or `alert` `$(".numberOfProfile0").length` before `if` and see what you are getting..

Comment: From where you are calling function trend?

Comment: I tried but it return error message "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" so the other codes /function don't  execute

Comment: use  $(".numberOfProfile0").html().length > 0 as in my updated answer

Comment: You should use a ajax pre-request callback function [beforeSend](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to check for the element and cancel to execute ajax based on the elements existence. See my answer for details.

Comment: Guys! jQuery selector is not a string. Using something like `$('.selector').val().length , $('.selector').html().length makes sense in jQuery rather than $('.selector').length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Please remember jQuery selector is not a string**. Using jQuery, the correct way to do this is something like `$('.selector').val().length , $('.selector').html().length`
 Use  `$(".numberOfProfile0").html().length > 0` in your code:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="numberOfProfile0">lorem</div>

<script>
if ( $(".numberOfProfile0").html().length > 0 ) {
  
   alert("success");
  
 // your function:
  
   //function trend() {
        //return $.ajax({
           // url: '/dashboard/getTrend' + '?period=30d' + "&profileId=" + //$(".numberOfProfile0").html(), //getting the api
           // type: 'get',
            //success: function(data) {

            //}
       // });
   // }
  
  }


</script>
```

Comment: you don't need to call `.length` on an `.html()` if you want to check elements existence inside dom. This should be enough to check that `$(".numberOfProfile0").length > 0`

Comment: @ Meer Please open your eye balls wide, before hitting the keyboard. It not only detects existence of div but also checks if it has any content. $(".numberOfProfile0").length > 0 is not sufficient to detect div. Research, try and then chime in.

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be

```
function trend() {
    if ( $(".numberOfProfile0").length ) {
        return $.ajax({
            url: '/dashboard/getTrend' + '?period=30d' + "&profileId=" + $(".numberOfProfile0").html(), //getting the api
            type: 'get',
            success: function(data) {

            }
        });
    }//if()
    else
    {
      return false; //or any other appropriate value
    }
}//trend()
```

Answer (score 1):

use `($(".numberOfProfile0").html() !== '')` that mean if element with class `.numberOfProfile0`  is not empty

```
function trend() {
   if ($(".numberOfProfile0").html().trim() !== '') { 
     $.ajax({
        url: '/dashboard/getTrend' + '?period=30d' + "&profileId=" + $(".numberOfProfile0").html(), //getting the api
        type: 'get',
        success: function(data) {

        }
     });
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it wrong! You are defining the function inside the `if`, where as you should be calling it inside `if`.

First define the function.

```
function trend() {
    return $.ajax({
        url: '/dashboard/getTrend' + '?period=30d' + "&profileId=" + $(".numberOfProfile0").html(), //getting the api
        type: 'get',
        success: function(data) {

        }
    });
}
```

Then call it.

```
if ($(".numberOfProfile0").length) {
    trend();   
}
```

OR

You can put the if check inside the function.

```
function trend() {
        if ($(".numberOfProfile0").length) {
             return $.ajax({
                 url: '/dashboard/getTrend' + '?period=30d' + "&profileId=" + $(".numberOfProfile0").html(), //getting the api
                 type: 'get',
                 success: function(data) {

                 }
             });
       }
       else{
            return -1;
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.is()` within `$.when()` at ternary to return `trend()` if element exists, else return `null` to `$.when()`; handle element not existing in `DOM`. Note, you can remove `success` option at `$.ajax()` if response is handled at `.done()`

```
function trend() {
  return $.ajax({
    url: "/dashboard/getTrend'"
         + "?period=30d" 
         + "&profileId=" 
         + $(".numberOfProfile0").html(), //getting the api
    type: "get"
  });
}

$.when($(".numberOfProfile0").is("*") ? trend() : null)
.done(function(trend1_data) {
  if (trend1_data === null) {
    // handle `$(".numberOfProfile0")` not existing in `DOM`
  } else {
    // handle `trend1_data` not being `null`, element exists
    // do something
  }
})
```

Answer (score -1):

You should check the existence of the element inside the [before_send](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) callback for aJax and cancel the aJax request if not.

```js
function trend() {
        return $.ajax({
            url: '/dashboard/getTrend' + '?period=30d' + "&profileId=" +        $(".numberOfProfile0").html(), 
            type: 'get',
            before_send: : function( xhr ) {
              if ($(".numberOfProfile0").length > 0  && $(".numberOfProfile0").html().trim() == ''){
                return false;
              }
            }
            success: function(data) {

            }
        });
    }
```

The above code snippet should work in your case.

Comment: @ArunSharma ok, in that case you should just change the if condition. my point here was that you should use `beforeSend` to achieve this, Just updated my answer with the regard.

Comment: It fails to detect if $(".numberOfProfile0") is empty because $(".numberOfProfile0")  is not a string. In jquery it shall  be $('.selector').val().length , $('.selector').html().length

Comment: if `$('.selector')` does not exist on page this statement `$('.selector').html().length` will definitely throw an exception, give it a shot.

Comment: The condition is to be executed only if $('.selector') exists. If it doesn't exists the condition simply fails without throwing any exception or error.